# Constantly changing msg.value, how to send correct amount

Tags: solidity, web3js

I am building a contract and web application, where users will run a function via a front-end and send funds into the contract. The amount they need to send in will be a percentage of the total ETH in the contract. This application will have many users so the total ETH in the contract will constantly be changing. How can I dynamically feed the correct amount of ETH from the front-end and to contract without it getting out of sync?

Answer (score 2):

There's no way of "pulling" Ether from the user, so the only solution is to generate a big `msg.value` and return any extra at the end of the transaction. This value can be thought as the max amount a user is willing to send, similar to a slippage check.

The solidity contract should look something like this:

```
function foobar() payable external {
  // Here you compute the fraction of total ether in the contract.
  // Careful that msg.value already entered the contract.
  uint256 requiredEther = _requiredEther();
  require(msg.value >= requiredEther, "msg.value too low");

  // Do your stuff here.
  // ...
  
  // Return extra to msg.sender.
  // This part must be at the end of the function to prevent re-entrancy exploits. 
  if (msg.value > requiredEther) {
    (bool success, ) = payable(msg.sender).call(){value: msg.value-requiredEther};
    require(success, "Reimbursement failed");
  }
}
```

On the frontend, you can read the `requiredEther` and add a small % to compute the `msg.value` to send.

Another solution is using Wrapped Ether (WETH) as transfer method since it can be pulled (with `transferFrom`). However users would need to do two extra transactions: one to wrap their Ether if they don't have any, and one to approve the contract.